# System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' in PresentationFramework.dll The method or operation is not implemented. ( MaterialMessageBox )

Tags: c#, wpf, messagebox

I'm trying to use the MaterialMessageBox [GitHub Source of the package](https://github.com/denpalrius/Material-Message-Box) , I have installed the package from the NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio 2019 . But when I executed the app , it throw an Exception in this line :

```
MaterialMessageBox.Show("Your cool message here", "The awesome message title");
```

> System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' in PresentationFramework.dll
> The method or operation is not implemented.

What might cause this error?

Comment: Is your nuget package included for the project using this line so the reference is added to the csproj? If so then maybe you need to add using BespokeFusion; to the class.

Comment: The reference of BespokeFusion is already exist in the references of my project.

Comment: And the using statement then?

Comment: Yes is present, if it is not present it will show an error not an Exception

Comment: My advice would be to reconsider using this package. Your immediate problem is probably because you're targetting .net core. Once I changed to net 4.8 I realised there's a dependency in this package on a very old version of mahapps metro: 1.2.4 When I downgraded to that I found i didn't like the version of materialdesignthemes

Comment: The version of materialdesigntheme is 2.0.0.638